# Using .NPMRC for Auth With NPM CI (in azure pipeline)

Tags: node.js, azure, npm, azure-pipelines

I am working on improving the build time for an azure pipeline that performs an NPM install.
As part of this, I decided to switch to `npm ci` instead of `npm install`.

However. In the pipeline prior to the NPM install, I currently have an authenticate task to allow access to some private NPM packages. When I run the pipeline with `npm install`, this works great. When I switched to `npm ci`, I get an auth error.

example yaml:

```yaml
    -job:
     steps:
      - task: npmAuthenticate@0
        inputs:
          workingFile: "$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/.npmrc"
      - script: npm install
      displayName: "npm install"
```

this is successful.

however, this:

```yaml
    -job:
     steps:
      - task: npmAuthenticate@0
        inputs:
          workingFile: "$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/.npmrc"
      - script: npm ci
      displayName: "npm ci"
```

returns the following auth error:

```
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, need: Bearer authorization_uri=https://login.windows.net/...
```

Am I missing something with how to use NPMRC auth with `npm ci`?

Comment: Try running "npm install" locally, commiting package-lock.json again and re-running the pipeline.

Comment: @LeonardoG does that mean the package-lock.json has to be generated with the same auth credentials as the pipeline runs under?

Comment: Possibly, but I am not entirely sure. It's worth a try, I've heard of that fixing similar issues. The only difference between `npm ci` and `npm i` should be the fact that `npm i` syncs the lockfile while `npm ci` performs a clean install without syncing the lockfile, only validating it. The environment under which your lockfile is generated should, I guess, closely resemble the pipeline environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to resolve your error, Make sure to you regenerate your token and use it in your yaml pipeline like below:-

**Link - https://www.npmjs.com/settings/username/tokens**

[image]

My **`.npmrc`** file with above token like below:-

```
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=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
```

[image]

Now you can use this **`.npmrc`** file for authentication and run npm install or npm ci script like below:-

**My YAML Pipeline:-**

```yaml
trigger:
  - main

jobs:
  - job: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

    steps:
      - task: NodeTool@0
        inputs:
          versionSpec: '14.x'
        displayName: 'Install Node.js'

      - checkout: self

      - script: |
          echo "//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=\npm_xxxx22G0rkYNeXK27JRK3" > .npmrc
        displayName: 'Create .npmrc file'

      - task: npmAuthenticate@0
        inputs:
          workingFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/.npmrc'


      - script: |
          npm install
        displayName: 'Install npm packages'
      
      - script: |
          npm ci
        displayName: 'Install npm packages'
```

**Code 2 without Create .npmrc step, Directly using the .nprmc file from Azure Repo:-**

```yaml
trigger:
  - main

jobs:
  - job: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

    steps:
      - task: NodeTool@0
        inputs:
          versionSpec: '14.x'
        displayName: 'Install Node.js'

      - checkout: self

      - task: npmAuthenticate@0
        inputs:
          workingFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/.npmrc'


      - script: |
          npm install
        displayName: 'Install npm packages'
      
      - script: |
          npm ci
        displayName: 'Install npm packages'
```

**Output1:-**

[image]

**Output2:-**

[image]

[image]